# Linux find command to get all text in the file and print file path

Tags: linux, grep, find, cat

I need get all the texts in the matching file in the folder , however at the same time need to get the matching file path as well . Can you please advise , how can I get the matching file path as well using below command

`find . -type f -name release.txt | xargs cat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the `cat` via `find` and use `-print` to return the file name:

```
find . -type f -name release.txt -print -exec cat '{}' \;
```

Comment: It's working and what i expected , can you please explain how -print help for get the path

Comment: When `find` finds a matching file, it returns the filename. However `-exec` suppresses this output in favor of the command given. `-print` then just does what it says: it explicitly prints the `find` result irregardless of `-exec`. More in `man find`

Comment: Is there ever a reason to quote the `{}`? I can't get GNU `find` to break when it's unquoted, even if names contain newlines, spaces and glob characters,  and since it is handled internally by `find` and not by the shell, I don't see why it would ever be needed. Am I missing something or are you quoting out of (good) habit?

Comment: @terdon `find -exec echo ${} \;` would be one method to break it. But yes, mainly its a deeply rooted habit.

Comment: `{}` doesn't match either a group command `{ list ; }` or a brace expansion e.g. (`{1,2,3}`) so is passed to find as-is by bash (and sh too - it's not a group command and posix sh doesn't implement brace expansions anyway).  BTW, `-printf` would work here too so you could, for example, use the same filename output as `tail` uses when given multiple files: `-printf "\n==> %p <==\n"`

Comment: and one other thing about how this works.  find's predicates are, by default, a chain of ANDed operations, with the next predicate only getting the filenames that the previous predicate returned true for.  `-type f` only returns true for regular files, `-print` (and `-printf` ) not only produces output, it also returns true for every filename it sees, so they are all passed on to the `-exec`.      And it doesn't have to end there.  If the `-exec` command were to use, say, `grep -q regex {} \;` instead of `cat {} \;`, another predicate could then act on filenames where grep returned true.

Comment: i.e. there's an implicit `-a` (AND) between each predicate.  You can also use `-o` for OR, but then you start needing to use parentheses to explicitly control the order of operations - e.g. `find . -type f \( -name release.txt -o -name other.txt \)`.   With the parentheses, it matches only regular files called release.txt or other.txt, without them it will match regular files called release.txt or any kind of file (regular, symlink, directory, named pipe, socket, etc) called other.txt